# How To Iterate over IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> When Serializing Data to CSV

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, ienumerable

I'm writing a C# class for serializing data to CSV format.
I wanted to make the class as generic as possible so that it will work for different types of data.

I first wrote the following method:

```
public void Serialize<T>(IEnumerable<T> pList)
    {
        _content.AppendLine(string.Join(_seperator, pList.Select(x => ObjectToCsvString(x)).ToArray()));
    }
```

I then realized that it would be nice to serialize objects such as lists of lists. So I added this method:

```
public void Serialize<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> pList)
    {
        if (pList != null && pList.Any())
        {
            foreach (IEnumerable<T> list in pList)
            {
                Serialize(list);
            }
        }
    }
```

So this didn't work. If I pass in a list of lists it will still go straight to the first method. I assume it might have to do with the fact that IEnumerable(IEnumerable(T)) technically is IEnumerable(T) as well. But I'm not really sure. I tried this method after that:

```
public void Serialize<T>(IEnumerable<T> pList)
    {
        if (pList != null && pList.Any())
        {
            if (pList is IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>) //example: list of lists of strings
            {
                foreach (IEnumerable<T> list in pList)
                {
                    Serialize(list);
                }
            }
            else //write CSV line
                _content.AppendLine(string.Join(_seperator, pList.Select(x => ObjectToCsvString(x)).ToArray()));
        }
    }
```

Similarly for this method the if statement was never executed when I passed in a list of lists of strings. The only way I was able to get it work with a list of list is with this method:

```
public void Serialize<T>(IEnumerable<T> pList)
    {
        if (pList != null && pList.Any())
        {
            if (pList is IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Object>>) //example: list of lists of strings
            {
                foreach (IEnumerable<Object> list in pList)
                {
                    Serialize(list);
                }
            }
            else //write CSV line
                _content.AppendLine(string.Join(_seperator, pList.Select(x => ObjectToCsvString(x)).ToArray()));
        }
    }
```

The questions I have are
1) Why do those 2 method not work for a list of lists?
2) Should I even be using generics for this? I feel like my understanding of generics is not sound.
3) Is there a better way to accomplish this for a list of lists?

Comment: " then realized that it would be nice to serialize objects such as lists of lists. " - since when is a CSV file a list of lists?

Comment: @MitchWheat He meant that originally he was serialising a list to CSV, and then he wanted to be able to serialise a list of lists to CSV as well.

Comment: "*Doesn't work*" is a nonsense. It does something, then you should describe what it does and what you expect, or you got some error(s) and then you should post that error(s). Error message is one of the most important things while debugging a code, and you don't care about it at all.

Comment: Can't imagine how a list of list would look like in csv. Can you elaborate?

Comment: So each list represents a line. After each object in the inner list move to next column. For each new list move down a row. @DawidFerenczy Did you read the rest of I wrote? If I try to call that method (passing in a list of lists of strings) it instead calls the first method. (as in a list of lists still get interpreted as  IEnumerable(T) and not IEnumerable(IEnumerable(T))

Comment: @Jason OK, I missed it, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply doesn't work because in

```
public void Serialize<T>(IEnumerable<T> pList)
{
    if (pList != null && pList.Any())
    {
        if (pList is IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>) //example: list of lists of strings
        {
            foreach (IEnumerable<T> list in pList)
            {
                Serialize(list);
            }
        }
        else //write CSV line
            _content.AppendLine(string.Join(_seperator, pList.Select(x => ObjectToCsvString(x)).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

You take in an IEnumerable as a parameter, an IEnumerable will never be an IEnumerable> T isn't a magic word, it's whatever was passed, so if you pass in a list of list of T then T is List and List is IEnumerable and not IEnumerable>

An easy way to handle of that is to worry about all of this Inside the loop instead of outside and handle everything at once is to avoid working with generic versions of T (since you pass this to a method that seems to be able to take any object further down the road) and do Something like this (changed to writing to the console for the example). This would even work with arbitrary lists and lists containing some list elements and some regular elements

```
void Main()
{
    List<object> mylist = new List<object> 
    {
        "test",
        DateTime.Now,
        new List<TimeSpan>()
        {
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
        }
    };

    Serialize(mylist);
}

public string ObjectToCSVString(object obj)
{
    return obj.ToString();
}

public void Serialize(IEnumerable Sequence)
{
    foreach (var item in Sequence)
    {
        if (item is IEnumerable && !(item is string)) // careful, string is IEnumerable<char>
        {
            Serialize(item as IEnumerable);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ObjectToCSVString(item));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ronan. That makes sense. I'll definitely test this out when I get a chance.